# Why does print the pointer directly give a diffrent result when print it by a function in my code?

Tags: c++

whats wrong here?
why the 2 "cout" didn't give the same results?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

template <class t>

class stack{
    private:
    
        struct node{
            t val;
            node *next;
        };
    
    public:
    
        node *top;
        
        stack(){
            top = NULL;
        }
    
        void push(t v){
            node item;
            item.val = v;
            item.next = top;
            top = &item;
        }
        
        void printNext(){
            cout << top->next <<endl;
        }
};

int main(){
    stack <int> s;
    s.push(10);
    
    cout << s.top->next << "\n";
    s.printNext();
    
    return 0;
}
```

when i directly trying to print the next pointer by

`cout << s.top->next << "\n";`

the result i got was "0"

but when i trying print the same pointer by the printNext() function

`cout << s.printNext(); << "\n";`

the result i got was "0x7f4a046aad5c"

so why it is not the same?

Comment: `node item;` The lifetime is too short to be worthwhile. At the end of the function you have a pointer to an invalid object in your list.

Comment: Anyway you have Undefined behavior as in `push` you create a local variable `item` and then use a pointer on it. However since it was local it's destroyed and no longer valid, yet your pointer remain to point on it

Comment: @Alex Larionov, ok, thanks i got it but still why my code give a different results?

Comment: The behaviour of Undefined behaviour is undefined. One day you could get what you expect and the next the computer hacks the pentagon and launches a nuclear strike to exterminate mankind.

Comment: `cout << s.printNext(); << "\n";` should not compile. The answer below is likely correct in its interpretation, but there's no way to prove it from the information we've been given.

Comment: @user4581301, thanks i got it

Comment: @user4581301 refer to my answer, because I think it's the true one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the possible picture of you program's stack (not your `stack` stack, but stack that contains all data of your program from start to finish)
:
[image]

The first state is after you execute `stack <int> s`, it contains your local variable `s` and the content of stack object (i.e. the pointer `top`, which now points to `NULL`).

The state 2 is when you enter function `s.push(10);` (not after it yet, but inside it). When you call it, there's some data added on stack that allows to return back from the function (not important, marked with crossed cell under `top`), next you have arguments of your function (the number 10 you pass), then your function creates a `node item` which consists of two variables for value and pointer on next. As a result of your `push` function, `top` now points on the location of `next`, while `next` points on 0 (i.e. pointer `next` is equal to 0).

The state 3 is right after you return from `push` function, all the local state of the function is again undefined (usually it's left untouched, but it's UNDEFINED, no guarantees about anything ever). Notice that `top` still points on undefined memory location.

The state 4 is when you call `cout << s.top->next << "\n";`, it's also a call to a function, so again it adds some technical data on stack, and also all the arguments (i.e. the copies of values of `s.top->next` and of `"\n"`). The copy contains the same address that is stored in `top` pointer, and it prints some undefined value, but you see `0`, because as I already said the value is marked undefined, but not changed, thus it's still `0` as in state 2.

Now finally why the second print isn't zero:
[image]

There you call a function, which adds some technical data on stack. Inside this function you call (!!) another function `cout<<`, so some more data has to be added, also you need to copy the argument again, i.e. the copy of values of `top->next` and new-line symbol too. However it just happened that this technical data now occupies the data that was previously occupied by `item.next` value, so it's overwritten, and no longer 0 (thus you see some garbage non-zero value).

Answer (score 0):

A pointer can print the function or variable ADDRESS. The second number that you got was the address of your function.
I hope I answered your question. If you want to know more about this go [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointers.htm)

have a fantastic day!

Comment: Hi, it's not how it actually works, refer to my answer, though it might be a bit overwhelming ;)

Comment: The syntax to take a function pointer would be much more complex than that